# How to insert multiple integer parameters into query?

Tags: api, ms-access, dapper

Website user can enter search criteria to query orders. User, States, Status, OrderID, etc.

Website communicates with API. Query parameters are in the header, so I assume they come in as strings. API communicates with Access via Dapper.

For some criteria, they can send multiple values. So I want to use an "IN" clause.

```
where UserID in (150, 3303, 16547)
```

Dapper handles this nicely.

```
connection.Query<int>("select * from table where Id in @Ids", new { Ids = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 } });
```

This works in MS-Access

```
SELECT top 100 * from Orders where UserID in (150, 30330)
```

But that only works when the values are ints. String and Strings both give "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" in Access.

```
SELECT top 100 * from Orders where UserID in ("150", "30330")  // two strings
SELECT top 100 * from Orders where UserID in ("150, 30330")  // single string
```

It may be a coincidence, but all the examples I see are integers. Access throws an error on strings if you don't specify the size. Using DynamicParameters makes it easy to specify the size.
But when the field is an int, my dapper code gives the same error (Data type mismatch in criteria expression):

```
var paramlist = new DynamicParameters();
if ((!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userId)) && userId != "0") {
    paramlist.Add("userId", userId, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input, 50);                
    sbWhere.AppendFormat("AND CustFID in (?) ", paramIndex++);
}
```

So I assume the issue is that I'm telling it that the parameter is a string.

But if I make the parameter an int, then it won't take the string with multiple values. Conversely, if I include the () in the string, it complains about the parens being missing from the 'in' clause.

I tried splitting the string of numbers into an array and/or list.

```
if ((!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userId)) && userId != "0") {
    var userIds = userId.Split(',');  //.ToList(); fails, can't map to native type
    paramlist.Add("userId", userIds, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input, 1000);
    if (userIds.Length > 1) {
        sbWhere.AppendFormat("AND CustFID in @userId ", paramIndex++);
    } else {
        sbWhere.AppendFormat("AND CustFID = @userId ", paramIndex++);                
    }
}
```

and it gives ": No mapping exists from object type System.String[] to a known managed provider native type." whether I say the parameters are int32 or string.

UPDATE:
There may be multiple search criteria, so I'm using DynamicParameters.
Here is my attempt at implementing Palle Due's idea.

```
if ((!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userId)) && userId != "0") {
//    var userIds = userId.Split(',').Select(i => Int32.Parse(i)).ToList();// fails, can't map to native type
   IEnumerable<int> userIds = userId.Split(',').Select<string, int>(int.Parse);
   paramlist.Add("userId", userIds, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);
   if (userIds.Count() > 1) {
      sbWhere.AppendFormat("AND CustFID in @userId ", paramIndex++);
   } else {
      sbWhere.AppendFormat("AND CustFID = @userId ", paramIndex++);                
   }
}

using (IDbConnection conn = Connection) {
   string sQuery = string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM vwweb_Orders {1}", columns, where);
   conn.Open();
   var result = await conn.QueryAsync<Order>(sQuery, paramlist);
   return result.ToList();
}
```

throws

```
Message: System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (Failed to convert parameter value from a SelectArrayIterator`2 to a Int32.)
----> System.InvalidCastException : Failed to convert parameter value from a SelectArrayIterator`2 to a Int32.
----> System.InvalidCastException : Object must implement IConvertible.
```

Comment: The number of parameters in a `WHERE x IN ( a, b, c )` clause cannot be parameterised - you'll have to use string concatenation for each parameter placeholder - or use a table-valued-parameter (but Access doesn't support table-valued-parameters).

Comment: To clarify my earlier comment: parameterising `WHERE ... IN` is impossible in standard SQL, however it does seem that Dapper handles `WHERE IN` as a special-case without needing RDBMS support. That's handy - I didn't know Dapper could do that! https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper#list-support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give up. Dapper should be able to handle this, but it's a newer feature, so...
I just built the IN clause myself.

```
if (userIds.Count() > 1) {
    sbWhere.AppendFormat("AND CustFID in ( ");
    int paramCnt = 0;
    foreach (int id in userIds) {
        sbWhere.AppendFormat("?, ");  // Access doesn't mind a trailing ,
        paramlist.Add("userId" + paramCnt.ToString(), id, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);
        paramCnt++;
    }
    sbWhere.AppendFormat(") ");
} else {
    sbWhere.AppendFormat("AND CustFID = ? ");
    paramlist.Add("userId", userIds.ToArray<int>()[0], DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The github page @Dai links to specifies that the Dapper list support only works with `IEnumerable<int>`.

But as I understand it your `UserID` is an int, so I don't get why you try to enter a string. You need to get the string the user has input and convert it to `IEnumerable<int>`. Do something like this:

```cs
IEnumerable<int> userIDs = (userId?? "").Split(',').Select<string, int>(int.Parse);
var result = connection.Query<int>("SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Orders WHERE UserID IN @Ids", new { Ids = userIDs });
```

You might want to apply some input checking to that, and you might also want to reconsider using Access as the "database" for a website. It's not what it was meant for.

Comment: Access: I haven't used Access this way before and don't plan to again, but it makes sense on this project for reasons. The backing store is Postgres, so there are none of the concurrency issues you would normally run into with Access. Access is just the business logic layer. And the decision is out of my hands.

Comment: The data comes in from the header as a string. There may be no userIds, one, or multiple. I'll update the question with the results from this approach.